# SQLite3Cursor object: how to access row values

Tags: pharo

I am fairly new to Pharo and trying hard to get a grip of it.

Installed the SQLite3 package and now I am trying to connect to local file based database.

I followed the Getting started tutorial of the community owned SQLite3 database client. Unfortunately only brief documentation is provided.

Can someone give me an example how to iterate through the SQLite3Cursor object and print them e.g. to the Transcript please?

Secondly I would like to know how I am able to access certain row values.

Appreciate any help for a newbie.
Thank you.

---

If I evaluate

```
cursor := connection execute: 'SELECT * FROM person;'
```

All persons are put in that `cursor` object. Basically I get n `SQLite3Rows` within that `cursor`. If I inspect `cursor next` I see the columns and values of that row but how can I display it in Transcript?

Second question is how can I iterate through the entire `cursor` object and send the output to Transcript?

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit on what exactly you are trying to do? Also write down in the question what have you tried so far. Finally, be aware that the tests are usually a good source of documentation. There are a lot under SQLite3-Core-Tests.

Comment: in that given example:

    cursor := connection execute: 'SELECT * FROM person;'.

puts all person in that cursor object. Basically I get n SQLite3Rows within that cursor object.

if I inspect `cursor next` I see the columns and values of that row but how can I display it in Transcript?

Second question is how can I iterate through the entire cursor object and send the output to Transcript?

thanks

Comment: To print `anObject` on the `Transcript` use `Transcript show: anObject`.

Comment: To print all elements in `aCollection` use `aCollection do: [:elem | Transcript crShow: elem]`.

Comment: the SQLite3Cursor object is per se not a collection as per my understanding. that is why aCollection do: [:elem | Transcript crShow: elem] fails.

Comment: Have you tried `cursor rows` to get a collection of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly you can do like this

```
| conn rs rows read|
conn := SQLite3Connection memory.
conn open.

conn execute: 'CREATE TABLE person(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER NOT NULL
);'.

conn execute: 'INSERT INTO person(name,age) VALUES (?2, ?1);' value: 25 value: 'Cyril'.

conn execute: 'INSERT INTO person(name,age) VALUES (?2, ?1);' value: 24 value: 'Marc'.

rs := conn execute: 'SELECT * FROM person;'.

""" OrderedCollection """
rows := rs rows.

rows do: [ :v |
    Transcript show: (v at: 'name'); cr.
     ]
```

The best is to look in SQLite3-Core-Tests